# disabling warnings/notices in syslog for centos 5.6

Tags: php, error-logging

I am trying to disable logging for notices and warnings generated by php into syslog. Following are some lines inside php.ini.

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR
```

I also ran php.ini and it showed me that my php.ini is in `/etc/php.ini`, so I am assuming I am editing correct file. Now I restart my `httpd`, but still I am seeing php warnings and notices in my `/var/log/messages` file that is written by syslog.

Am pulling my hair as I am not able to figure out what must be the reason for this pretty straight forward issue

Also in my `httpd.conf` I have :

```
LogLevel error
```

Also, when i run php -i | grep error, i get following output:

```
[root@xx-xx-xx-xx ~]# php -i | grep error
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => /var/log/error_log => /var/log/error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
**error_reporting => 4177 => 4177**
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Other interesting options for that function:

```
<?php

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Comment: this is not what i need, i need it globally and not for particular script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this line in your php file?

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: am not talking of doing it in a php script, i need a global setting, probably it is to be done configuring syslog to filter out warnings